# Problems importing Prestashop products 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I have imported the products from a prestashop 1.6 to another prestashop 1.7. When accessing the backoffice, the products and related information are displayed correctly, but in front (store) the products are not displayed.

I have been researching and to see the products in the store I must enter each of the products and "Save", after saving the product from the backoffice, the product is already displayed in the store.

Any solution to not having to enter each product keeping each of them?

Comment: How exactly did you import them? Did you use default PrestaShop functionality for that, some specific plugin, did you do it “manually” via SQL ex- and imports …?

Comment: I have imported the information via SQL (manual import table to table), following the official migration documentation provided by Prestashop. https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/keeping-up-to-date/migration/

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I forgot to import the contents of the table 'category_product'.